# SQL Update value in database if exists more than a specified number of times

Tags: sql-server

I am working on the stored procedure below but running into issues. My issue is that if the [breed] column has the same value in the table more than specified based on a variable, I need to update the table with another breed value from the same table that is listed in the table < the specified amount of times. For example, 'pitbull' is in the table 6 times and 'boxer' is in the table 4 times. They both need to be listed in the database 5 times each based on the specified value of 'BreedListed' that is = 5. I am attempting to write an update query to update the [breed] value so all [breeds] will be listed 5 times. Thanks for input.

```
create table #TempCanine (AppID INT, Breed varchar(8), age INT) 

--insert statments not included in stored procedure. They are oncase anyone wanted to recreate the sample data.
insert into #TempCanine values(101, 'Pitbull', 2)
insert into #TempCanine values(102, 'Boxer', 4)
insert into #TempCanine values(103, 'Pitbull', 1)
insert into #TempCanine values(104, 'Pitbull', 5)
insert into #TempCanine values(105, 'Boxer', 2)
insert into #TempCanine values(106, 'Pitbull', 2)
insert into #TempCanine values(107, 'Boxer', 8)
insert into #TempCanine values(108, 'Pitbull', 1)
insert into #TempCanine values(109, 'Pitbull', 3)
insert into #TempCanine values(110, 'Boxer', 8)


DECLARE @Counter INT
DECLARE @BreedListed int
DECLARE @GetBreed varchar(50)
SET @BreedListed = 5
SET @Counter = 1


WHILE @COUNTER <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempCanine) BEGIN
   SELECT @GetBreed = breed
   FROM #TempCanine
   WHERE ID = @Counter AND COUNT(breed) > @BreedListed

--LOST
  IF @GetBreed <> NULL
  BEGIN
        UPDATE #TempCanine
        SET T.breed = (SELECT breed
        FROM #TempCanine T INNER JOIN #TempCanine C
    ---LOST HERE
    END


    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
  END
```

Comment: that doesn't look like an update.. more of a delete or insert.

Comment: I included the INSERT statements just in case anyone wanted to create the temp table with data. They are not normally in my stored procedure. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This will never return true:

```
IF @GetBreed <> NULL
```

The correct way to write this is

```
IF @GetBreed IS NOT NULL
```